# How to disabling built in system in mouse, and how to disable the RGB light... im using y-fruitful mouse... (im new in linux sorry)

Tags: command-line, mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-pointer, magic-mouse

i have a problem with my new mouse called "Y-FRUITFUL" https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:10c4-8105

my problem :
this mouse have an built in system. when i hold down right click, i feel the sensitivity turning down. and when i relase the right click... the cursor will freeze for a seccond and then get back to normal sensitivity. i want to turned off that feature but i dont know how.
i really glad if someone expert come to help. thanks

what ive tried so far:

- searching mouse software(theres no specific apps to set this mouse)
- piper

Comment: What OS & release are you using?